# Still get error Unable to load dynamic library '/home/max/mongo/bin/mongo'

Tags: php, mongodb

I opened package and installed `mongoDB` and got:

```
[root@feeder /]# cd /home/max/mongodb-linux-i686-2.4.3/bin
[root@feeder bin]# ls -l
total 231700
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17828204 Apr 23 00:01 bsondump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9181648 Apr 23 00:04 mongo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17882692 Apr 23 00:03 mongod
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17885740 Apr 22 23:56 mongodump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17840780 Apr 22 23:57 mongoexport
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17883768 Apr 23 00:00 mongofiles
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17852780 Apr 22 23:58 mongoimport
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17832300 Apr 23 00:00 mongooplog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17832876 Apr 23 00:02 mongoperf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17890796 Apr 22 23:56 mongorestore
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13491532 Apr 23 00:03 mongos
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17795196 Apr 23 00:02 mongosniff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17877452 Apr 22 23:58 mongostat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17832268 Apr 22 23:59 mongotop
```

- Added link: `mongo -> mongodb-linux-i686-2.4.3`
- Created `data` folder: `mkdir /mongo/data`
- initiated mongo: `mongo/bin/mongod --dbpath=mongo/data`

All works fine and can connect with mongoVUE monitor tool.

So far so good.

Now, I try to connect to BongoDB from PHP:

I added to `php.ini` (`nano /etc/php.ini`): `extension=/home/max/mongo/bin/mongo`

and restarted `httpd`: `/etc/init.d/httpd restart`

from code:

```
$conn = new Mongo('localhost');
```

I get an error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/max/mongo/bin/mongo' - /home/max/mongo/bin/mongo: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 in Unknown on line 0

**PS**

I tried also: `extension=/home/max/mongo/bin/mongo.so` but still get the same error.

Did I miss something?

**Additional Info** from phpinfo()

- PHP Version => 5.3.16
- MongoDB:  mongodb-linux-i686-2.4.3
- OS: CentOS release 5.2 (Final)

Please, help

Thanks,

**[EDIT]**
I have PHP 64 bit, according to Farkie, I installed bongoDB 64 bit. Still get error but without "worng ELF":

```
 php -i | grep mongo
```

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/max/mongo/bin/mongo' - /home/max/mongo/bin/mongo: cannot dynamically load executable in Unknown on line 0

I don't see `mongo.so` under `/usr/lib64/php/modules/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a 64bit mongo.so, but a 32bit version of PHP (Or the other way round).

Comment: Sounds like I have 64 bit PHP and installed 32bit mongoDB. Going to reinstall to 64 bit. Thanks

Comment: Cool - let us know if you fix it or not!

Comment: Hey mate, I installed bongodb 64 bit, get other error, please ,see the EDIT

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you configure PHP for Mongo. Read the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php) and you'll find out that there is a specific PHP extension you have to build.

Comment: The Link documentation is broken. BTW, I don't have mongo.so also